# Samba as AD member: "force user" confused by identical local & domain user names

Tags: user-accounts, samba, active-directory, windows-domain

I am running Samba 4.9.1 on RHEL7, joined to a Win AD domain. In one share, I set

```
force user = foo
```

, hoping to force the *local* user foo. However, the same user name also exists in the AD, and Samba actually uses the AD user e.g. upon file creation.

```
getent passwd foo
```

returns the local user, as expected, since /etc/nsswitch.conf reads

```
passwd: files winbind
group: files winbind
```

Obviously, I set the option

```
winbind use default domain = yes
```

in smb.conf, and I would prefer not to change that, since I am not sure how many things I would need to change elsewhere then...

Any hints how to force Samba to look for local users first?

Regards,
Eric

Comment: Fyi, I now "solved" this by removing 'force user' altogether and going for (default) ACLs on the shared directory, which is probably the cleanest way to do it. This also allows to see which user created which new file.
Leaving the question open however, since that might not be a feasible way for others (e.g. on filesystems without ACL support).

Comment: Please add this as an answer and accept it so that others can easily find your solution in the future.

Comment: Did you find a real solution to the problem. I do NOT want AD users to own files at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as Worthweile asked for it, I will post my workaround as an answer.

1. Remove "force user" directive from share definition. This will make newly created files owned by the currently authenticated share user and his/her primary group.
2. If necessary, e.g. on ext2/3 file systems, enable ACLs via mount options. In my case (xfs), ACLs are always available by default.
3. `setfactl -R -m u:foo:rwX <share_dir>
   setfactl -R -d -m u:foo:rwX <share_dir>`

The first command will grant user `foo` read, write and execute permissions to all files and directories within the share. The capital `X` will set execute permissions only if it is a directory or someone else already has execute permission, as stated in `man setfactl`.

The second one will add the same permission as default for new files within the share.

Probably, Samba's `force user` option is in most cases actually a workaround for insufficient priviledge management, so this should be the cleanest way (the Linux equivalent to 'pythonic', maybe?). However, there will probably still be situations where ACLs are not applicable, so the question about `force user`'s behaviour remains.